# Is there any example to customize current Streamlit component

Tags: python, streamlit

In the streamlit doc of component, it says:

> Custom versions of existing Streamlit elements and widgets, such as
> st.slider or st.file_uploader.

But there's no such example of doing it except creating a brand new component from scratch. Is there any tutorial that can help me to extend current component, for example st.file_uploader, to add a new custom JavaScript?